# EChart series with multi tooltip

Tags: reactjs, charts, tooltip, echarts, depth

I need to get the eCharts multi tooltip on the trading depth chart like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D25N.png)
This is my config in react:

```
{
      xAxis: {
        type: 'value',
        scale: true,
        splitLine: {
          show: false
        },
        min: series[0].data[bidLen - 1][0],
        max: series[1].data[askLen - 1][0]
      },
      yAxis: {
        type: 'value',
        scale: true,
        splitLine: {
          show: false
        },
        axisTick: {
          show: false
        },
        axisLabel: {
          show: false
        },
        axisLine: {
          show: false
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        show: true,
        trigger: 'axis',
        axisPointer: {    
          type: 'shadow'   
        }
      },
      grid: {
        left: '0',
        right: '0',
        top: '0',
        bottom: '30',
      },
      series: series
    }
```

How can I achieve multiple tooltips appearing at the same time

This feature is currently not supported directly in community
https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/11382#issuecomment-543036896